# My husband and I have been separated for 4 months, and he gave me divorce 2 weeks ago, do I need to observe iddah?

Tags: talaq, relationships, iddah

My husband and I have been separated for 4 months, after he got arrested. He was on bail and was not allowed to return to the family home. In this time I have demanded that he gives me talaaq (divorce). Finally he gave me talaaq 2 weeks ago.

My question is do I still need to observe the idaat (waiting) period as we have had no sexual relations in this time.